# Insert rows in my listview from a thread

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listview, delegates

I have to create a really simple application in vb. My app contains a button and a listview. In my application i have to run threads, and insert in a listview the name and time of the thread executed. My code starts when i click on the threading button

my code is the following

```
Private Sub btnThreading_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnThreading.Click
    Try       
        For index = 0 To 3    
            Dim th As New Threading(index)                
            Me.Invoke(New DoStuffDelegate(AddressOf th.Run))
        Next    
        lstText.View = View.Details
        lstText.Columns.Add("Thread Name")
        lstText.Columns.Add("Time")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

And the page threading is the following

```
    Public Class Threading
    Private threadName As String
    Dim value As Date    
    Private Delegate Sub DoStuffDelegate()
    Dim lockthis As New Object       
    Sub New(ByVal ThreadName As String)
        Me.threadName = "Thread Number : " & ThreadName
    End Sub        

    Public Sub Run()    
            For index = 0 To 3
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
                value = Date.Now
                Console.WriteLine(threadName & " Time : " & value)
                Dim item3 As New ListViewItem(Me.threadName)
                item3.SubItems.Add(Me.value)
                Form1.lstText.Items.AddRange(New ListViewItem() {item3})
            Next   
    End Sub      
End Class
```

if I use a thread without the delegate like the following

`Dim th As New Threading(index)
     Dim trd = New Thread(AddressOf th.Run)
     trd.start()`

, my output window shows the names and threads as it should for example

Thread Number : 1 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 2 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 3 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00

but doesn't show anything in the list view. but if i choose to use the delegate like the following,

```
    Dim th As New Threading(index)
    Me.Invoke(New DoStuffDelegate(AddressOf th.Run))
```

it shows the following in the output

Thread Number : 1 Time : 9/15/2014 9:50:59
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 2 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:01
Thread Number : 3 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:02

and it shows it in the listview.So it works but doesn't execute the code as a thread does. But finally when I use the following code

```
Dim th As New Threading(index)
Dim trd = New Thread(AddressOf th.Run)
Me.Invoke(New DoStuffDelegate(AddressOf trd.Start))
```

, my output window shows the names and threads as it should for example

Thread Number : 1 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 2 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 3 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00

but doesn't show anything in the list view.

I want the list view to show this

Thread Number : 1 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 2 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00
Thread Number : 3 Time : 9/15/2014 9:51:00

All threads should have the same time, all threads should start at the same time,and they should appear in my list view.

Please help, I've been working on this for like two weeks and I'm not finding any solution!

Answer (score 0):

What are you adding to the `ListView`?  The name and the time, right?  So, when you invoke a method on the UI thread, pas the name AND the time.  Don't wait until you're on the UI thread to get the time because obviously that's going to be later.

Comment: I passed the time in the constructor of threading my result was the following :Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/16/2014 9:42:40 AM
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/16/2014 9:42:40 AM
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/16/2014 9:42:44 AM
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/16/2014 9:42:48 AM
Thread Number : 0 Time : 9/16/2014 9:42:52 AM

Comment: So we still have the same problem here, the threads are not working at the same time.

Comment: I've looked closer at your code and I'm afraid that it's basically garbage.  You need to go right back to the drawing board.  Do you know what the `Invoke` method is for?  The whole point of the `Invoke` method is to execute a method on the thread that owns a control.  That means that you are executing that `Run` method on the UI thread every time.  There are no additional threads because you haven't created any.

Comment: yeah I'm new at this. It's the first time that i use the invoke method, i'll get back at this later but thanks for your time!

Comment: Generally, you start a thread either directly (`Thread` class) or indirectly (`Task` class, etc.) and then you use the `Invoke` method in order to update the UI.  The `Invoke` method ensures that the executed method runs on the UI thread and can therefore successfully modify one or more controls owned by that thread.